# Is hash code of java.lang.String really cached?

Tags: java, string, caching, immutability

```
String s1 = "String1";      
System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); // return an integer i1 


Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");  
field.setAccessible(true);  
char[] value = (char[])field.get(s1);  
value[0] = 'J';  
value[1] = 'a';  
value[2] = 'v';  
value[3] = 'a';  
value[4] = '1'; 
System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); // return same value of integer i1
```

Here even after I changed the characters with the help of reflection, same hash code value is mainatained.

Is there anything I need to know here?

Comment: If it's the same value, then it is cached. What other proof do you need? Go to the source code.

Comment: Cool. Another question would be `When it's re-evaluated ?`

Comment: Using Reflection breaks the API of String, which causes this unexpected behaviour

Comment: @kocko: never, since String is immutable (unless the computed hashCode is 0, which also means "not computed yet")

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks. Really cool question for interview. :)

Comment: @JBNizet: "the computed hashCode is 0" does not necessarily mean "not computed yet". It is possible to have a computed value of 0 for the hash value, in which case, it will be recalculated at each call to `hashCode()`. here is a page describing how to create a String with any given hash value

`https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/unhashing-a-string`

Actually the string "f5a5a608" has a hash code of 0;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `String` is meant to be immutable. As such, there is no point having to recalculate the hashcode. It is cached internally in a field called `hash` of type `int`.

`String#hashCode()` is implemented as (Oracle JDK7)

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

where `hash` initially has a value of `0`. It will only be calculated the first time the method is called.

As stated in the comments, using reflection breaks the immutability of the object.