# Find duplicate value from string array

Tags: java, arrays

I found two way to find the duplicate value from string array.

First way :

```
private static String FindDupValue(String[] sValueTemp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sValueTemp.length; i++) {
      String sValueToCheck = sValueTemp[i];
      if(sValueToCheck==null || sValueToCheck.equals(""))continue;
      for (int j = 0; j < sValueTemp.length; j++) {
        if(i==j)continue;
        String sValueToCompare = sValueTemp[j];
        if (sValueToCheck.equals(sValueToCompare)){
          return sValueToCompare;
        }
      }

    }
    return "";

  }
```

Second way :

```
private static String FindDupValueUsingSet(String[] sValueTemp) {
    Set<String> sValueSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String tempValueSet : sValueTemp) {
      if (sValueSet.contains(tempValueSet))
        return tempValueSet;
      else
        if(!tempValueSet.equals(""))
          sValueSet.add(tempValueSet);
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Both methods are correct.

My question is which one best method and why? Or is there any other best way to find out duplicate value form an array?

Answer (score 2):

Nice thing about Set is that it's [add operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) returns
`true` if this set did not already contain the specified element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    String[] stringsToTest = {"a", "b", "c", "a"};

    for (String s : stringsToTest) {
        boolean notInSetYet = set.add(s);

        if (!notInSetYet) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Duplicate: a

Answer (score 1):

Second way.

Using a Set is much more efficient for this operation because `sValueSet.contains(tempValueSet)` uses the backing map (and hence hash codes and fast lookup times) instead of fully iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the approaches are almost similar in terms of algorithmic complexity.

The first approach's complexity is `O(N * N)`, where `N` is the length of the array. I don't think it's necessary to explain why, but just in case it is - the nested loops take `N * N` units of time, which gives the complexity.

As for the second approach - having a `HashSet` allows you to search with constant complexity (`O(1)`), because the search is based on the hashed value of the `String`. One can think that this approach is more effective, but in reality it isn't that much, because we need to encounter the *insert* operation on the `HashSet`.

Adding to the `HashSet` is of complexity `O(N)` (worst case scenario). For `N` String objects, you might have `N` insert operations, which again gives complexity of `O(N * N)`.

So, to summarize, both of the approaches are of similar expense. I would prefer the second one, though, as it's a bit more readable.

Comment: HashSet insertion complexity even in the worst case scenario is still amortized `O(1)`, not `O(n)`

Comment: It's `O(1)` if you know the size of the set, otherwise it's `O(n)`

Comment: no, even if you don't know the size, it's **amortized** `O(1)`. when you don't know the size and it reaches the worst case (current number of items >= available size), the set will grow ONCE based on load factor (and initial capacity). there's nothing going `O(n)` there. Java documentation guarantees that.

Comment: @LeleDumbo it's O(1) per item if the hash spreads the keys *used* (as opposed to potential ones). Worst case is if all the hashcodes collide: through java7 that was a linked list and O(N), but java8 switches to a tree and appears to be O(log N). There were denial-of-service attacks based on this where you could send e.g. Tomcat or IIS an HTTP request containing several thousand URL parameters chosen to collide and it would take hours of CPU to process instead of a tenth of a second.

Answer (score 1):

in your first approach in the second loop i believe if you change the loop starting point from j=0 to j=i it will make it faster. because you will avoid comparing 2 values twice

```
private static String FindDupValue(String[] sValueTemp) {
for (int i = 0; i < sValueTemp.length; i++) {
  String sValueToCheck = sValueTemp[i];
  if(sValueToCheck==null || sValueToCheck.equals(""))continue;
  for (int j = i; j < sValueTemp.length; j++) {
    if(i==j)continue;
    String sValueToCompare = sValueTemp[j];
    if (sValueToCheck.equals(sValueToCompare)){
      return sValueToCompare;
    }
  }

}
return "";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be one of the fastest approaches, running in O(n), assuming an amortized O(1) for `HashSet.add`, plus requiring only one hash computation per iteration by omitting the use of `contains`.
It's true that String caches hashcode (thanks to Jonah), this code generalizes the concept of omitting 
`contains`.

```
private static String FindDupValueUsingSet(String[] sValueTemp) {
    Set<String> sValueSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String tempValueSet : sValueTemp)
        if (!tempValueSet.equals("")) //exclude empty Strings (add null checking if required)
            if (!sValueSet.add(tempValueSet))
                return tempValueSet;
    return "";
}
```

Comment: "plus requiring only one hash computation per iteration" hashCode of String (an Immutable) is cached, so no recomputatoin, no matter how many times you use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000611/is-hash-code-of-java-lang-string-really-cached

Comment: Yes that's true for Strings